# My styles break when i tried to make them responsive (duplicate classes) - Landing page with next.js and styled components

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, styled-components

The stuff that is happening is quite weird, and i don't know what is going on overall, so i'll give you my best explication.

I have this landing page with three different components

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Costurería Gloria</title>
      </Head>

      {/* Presentation */}
      <Presentation />
      {/* Description */}
      <Description />
      {/* types of works */}
      <DifferentWorks />
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

And these are the styles of the two first components ( the third one doesn't really matter ! )

(You probably don't need to read all the styles, but i put them there if it's needed !)

Presentation

```
import styles from "styled-components";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

// Responsive presentation

const ResponsivePresentation = {
  responsive1: "@media screen and (max-width: 1300px)",
  responsive2: "@media screen and (max-width: 1100px)",
  responsive3: "@media screen and (max-width: 850px)",
  responsive4: "@media screen and (max-width: 750px)",
  responsive5: "@media screen and (max-width: 650px)",
  responsive6: "@media screen and (max-width: 550px)",
  responsive7: "@media screen and (max-width: 470px)",
  responsive8: "@media screen and (max-width: 370px)"
};

//

export const PresentationHero = styles.section`

width: 100%;
height: 663px;

display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

overflow: hidden;

`;

export const PresentationText = styles.div`

position: relative;

width: 50%;
height: 663px;

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;

h1{
    font-size: 12rem;

    padding-top: 2.3rem;

    font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;
}

p{
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    font-weight: 300; 

    padding-right: 7rem;
    padding-top: 8.5rem;
}

overflow: hidden;

`;

export const PresentationUnderText = styles(motion.div)`

width: 500px;
height: 1.6px;

position: absolute;
bottom: 41%;

z-index: 10;

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive1}{
    width: 460px;
    height: 1.2px;
    bottom: 40.5%;
}

`;

export const PresentationScissor = styles(motion.div)`

width: 50px;
height: 50px;

transform: rotateZ(35deg);

position: absolute;
bottom: 36.8%;
left: 3%;

z-index: 15;

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive1}{
    width: 35px;
    bottom: 37.6%;
    height: 35px;
}

`;

export const PresentationBackground = styles.div`

position: relative;

width: 50%;
height: 663px;

`;

// Second layout

export const PresentationHero2 = styles.div`

position: relative;

width: 100%;
height: 663px;

display: flex; 
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

overflow: hidden;

`;

export const PresentationWrapper2 = styles(motion.div)`

position: relative;

width: 100%;
height: 663px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(123, 8, 255, 0.9), rgb(123, 8, 255, 0.87));

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;

h1{
    font-size: 12rem;
    font-family: 'Oleo Script', cursive;

    padding-top: 7rem;

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive2}{
        font-size: 11rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive3}{
        font-size: 10.3rem;
        padding-top: 9rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive4}{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11rem;
        padding-top: 4rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive5}{
        padding-top: 2rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive6}{
        font-size: 10rem;
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive7}{
        font-size: 8rem;
        padding-top: 4rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive8}{
        font-size: 7rem;
        padding-top: 6rem;
    }
}

p{
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    font-weight: 300; 
    text-align: center;

    padding-top: 18rem;

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive2}{
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive3}{
        font-size: 2.2rem;
        padding-top: 21rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive4}{
        font-size: 2.1rem;
        padding-top: 13.5rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive6}{
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive7}{
        padding-top: 16rem;
        font-size: 1.9rem;
    }

    ${ResponsivePresentation.responsive8}{
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        padding-top: 17rem;
    }
}

overflow: hidden;


`;

export const PresentationUnderText2 = styles(motion.div)`

width: 500px;
height: 1.6px;

position: absolute;
bottom: 50%;

z-index: 10;

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive2}{
    width: 450px;
    height: 1.2px;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive3}{
    bottom: 47%;
    width: 420px;
    height: 1px;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive4}{
    width: 340px;
    bottom: 39%;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive5}{
    width: 260px;
    bottom: 41%;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive6}{
    width: 220px;
    bottom: 46%;
    height: 1.6px;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive7}{
    width: 160px;
    bottom: 49%;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive7}{
    width: 130px;
    height: 2px;
}

`;

export const PresentationScissor2 = styles(motion.div)`

width: 50px;
height: 50px;

transform: rotateZ(35deg);

position: absolute;
bottom: 45.8%;
left: 15%;

z-index: 15;

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive2}{
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    bottom: 46.85%;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive3}{
    bottom: 43.9%;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive4}{
    bottom: 35.9%;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive5}{
    bottom: 37.8%;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive6}{
    bottom: 42.8%;
}

${ResponsivePresentation.responsive7}{
    width: 35px;
    bottom: 46%;
    height: 35px;
}

`;
```

Description

```
import styles from "styled-components";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

// Description responsive

const ResponsiveDescription = {
  responsive1: "@media screen and (max-width: 1260px)",
  responsive2: "@media screen and (max-width: 1190px)",
  responsive3: "@media screen and (max-width: 1100px)",
  responsive4: "@media screen and (max-width: 1050px)"
};

//

export const DescriptionHero = styles(motion.section)`

position: relative;

width: 100%;
height: 663px;

display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

margin-top: 10rem;

overflow: hidden;

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive4}{
    height: 750px;
}

`;

export const DescriptionWrapper = styles(motion.div)`

width: 100%;
height: 100%;

display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

overflow: hidden;

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive3}{
    justify-content: space-between;
}

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive4}{
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

`;

export const SmallSquare = styles.div`

position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;

width: 40px;
height: 40px;

background: #FF3471;

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive4}{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;

    display: none;
}

`;

export const DescriptionImg = styles.div`

width: 45%;
height: 100%;

display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

div{
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 400px;

    ${ResponsiveDescription.responsive2}{
        width: 200px;
        height: 360px;
    }

    ${ResponsiveDescription.responsive4}{
        width: 180px;
        height: 300px;
    }

}

overflow: hidden;

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive3}{
    width: 38%;
}

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive4}{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

`;

export const DescriptionText = styles.div`

width: 55%;
height: 100%;

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

overflow: hidden;

h2{
    font-size: 6rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;

    ${ResponsiveDescription.responsive2}{
        font-size: 5.5rem;
    }

    ${ResponsiveDescription.responsive4}{
        font-size: 5rem;
        padding-right: 0rem;
    }

}

p{
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: left;

    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-top: 3rem;

    ${ResponsiveDescription.responsive2}{
        font-size: 2.6rem;
    }

    ${ResponsiveDescription.responsive4}{
        font-size: 2.3rem;
        text-align: center;

        padding-top: 2rem;
    }

}

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive4}{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}

`;

export const DescriptionScissor = styles(motion.div)`

position: absolute;
top: 2%;
left: 40%;

transform: rotateZ(127deg);

width: 50px;
height: 50px;

z-index: 10;

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive2}{
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;

    left: 40.1%;
}

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive3}{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    left: 38.5%;
}

`;

export const DescriptionLines = styles(motion.div)`

position: absolute;
top: 14%;
left: 42.1%;

width: 1.5px;
height: 530px;

z-index: 1;

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive1}{
    width: 1px;
    height: 525px;

    left: 42.2%;
}

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive2}{
    height: 500px;
}

${ResponsiveDescription.responsive3}{
    height: 480px;
    left: 40.5%;
}

`;
```

Now, in the second component, when i was trying to make it responsive, everything looks cool.

This is how presentation looks like

[image]

And this is how description looks like

[image]

Now, when i tried to make the screen smaller, this is how my Description component looks like..

[image]

Now, if i go to chrome dev tools, these are the classes of each component...

[image]

The first component ( Presentation ) has a class of presentation, and that's correct, but, my second component, Description, also has the class of Presentation, but, with the items of Description component, so, what the hell is going on there ? And if you look the third component, it has the class of Description, but doesn't have no items at all ( like is supposed to ), this ain't firs time this happens, can someone explain to me why does this breake this way ?

Thanks for your time homies !

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know what is the main issue, but, i figured something out

You might have your component like this

```
return (
<>
...Component's stuff..
</>
)
```

You need to change that to this

```
return (
<div>
...Component's stuff..
</div>
)
```

And the reason i think this is working, is because, it's like this separates the component from others so it doesn't confuse them, thinking that they all are the same, so the div in each component generates the oportunity to isolate your component so to speak